# How can I add custom font in this flutter code

Tags: android, flutter, dart, fonts, custom-font

I need to add my own custom font file to the code below. I don't want to use google fonts here.
How can I add custom font. I already added the font file in pubspec.yaml and the folder.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

/// Google fonts constant setting: https://fonts.google.com/
TextTheme kTextTheme(theme, String language) {
  switch (language) {
    case 'vi':
      return GoogleFonts.montserratTextTheme(theme);
    case 'ar':
      return GoogleFonts.ralewayTextTheme(theme);
    default:
      return GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme(theme);
  }
}

TextTheme kHeadlineTheme(theme, [language = 'en']) {
  switch (language) {
    case 'vi':
      return GoogleFonts.montserratTextTheme(theme);
    case 'ar':
      return GoogleFonts.ralewayTextTheme(theme);
   
    default:
      return GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme(theme);
  }
}
```

Comment: In the cookbook guide of the flutter documentation you can find a tutorial of how to add a custom font: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: I know how to add custom fonts. I just want to know how to add that font to this code.

Comment: I know how to add custom fonts. I just want to know how to add that font to this code as in the format. I want to pass the arguments and return the font which I needed. Thanks

Comment: As I have answered below you can just return the Textstyle

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy your font file to the assets folder or where ever you wish and add it to pubspec.yaml font section.

.yaml file:

```
# example:
  fonts:
    - family: Lato
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf
```

After this basic setup you can directly use the added font in the TextStyle and return that instead of the GoogleFont

```
TextTheme kTextTheme(theme, String language) {
  switch (language) {
    case 'vi':
      return return TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Lato',
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 18,
    );
    case 'ar':
      return return TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Lato',
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 18,
    );
    default:
      return return TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Lato',
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 18,
    );
  }
}
```